# how to handle error in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I am not sure how to handle errors of api request in a reducer using redux.

i have the following in my reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case APPROVE_COMMSMATRIX_SOX:
    case FETCH_COMMSMATRIX:
        if (action.payload.data.header.error) {

            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                error: {
                    code: "INVALID ACTION",
                    message: action.payload.data.header.message,
                    action
                }
             });

       } else {
           return { ...state, [action.payload.data.body.recordset.record[0].id] : action.payload.data.body.recordset.record[0] };
       }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

My api call is returning a valid error but how can i display this to the user?
This is how i have it in my component to handle reducer errors. i am checking if error exists in the state object that is returned by the reducer and rendering the message onto the page by setting the state

```
class Approve extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.runOnce = false;
        this.initConfirm = this.initConfirm.bind(this);
        this.state = {
                message : <div>Confirming...<i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.approveCommsmatrixSox(id);
    }

    initConfirm(){
        this.runOnce = true;
        if(this.props.approvecommsmatrix.error){
            this.setState({ message: this.props.approvecommsmatrix.error.message}); 
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { approvecommsmatrix } =  this.props ;

        if(!this.runOnce && approvecommsmatrix !== undefined && Object.keys(approvecommsmatrix).length > 0 ){
            this.initConfirm();
        }

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row-fluid top-buffer">{this.state.message}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ commsmatrices }, ownProps) {
    if(commsmatrices.error){
        return { approvecommsmatrix : commsmatrices };
    }
    return { approvecommsmatrix : commsmatrices[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        { approveCommsmatrixSox },
        dispatch
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { approveCommsmatrixSox })(Approve);
```

**UPDATE**

i have updated the component to display error message and returning the error in the reducer.

```
initConfirm(){
        this.runOnce = true;
        if(this.props.approvecommsmatrix.error){
            this.setState({ message: this.props.approvecommsmatrix.error.message}); 
        }else{

        }
    }
```

In my reducer i do not understand how to call another `error case` as you mentioned in answer.

**actions**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_COMMSMATRIX = 'fetch_commsmatrix';

export function fetchCommsmatrix(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`/api/user/comms/matrices/id/`+id+`/format/json?quiet=1`);    
    return {
        type: FETCH_COMMSMATRIX,
        payload: request
    };
}

export const FETCH_COMMSMATRICES_BY_SERVICE = 'fetch_commsmatrices_by_service';

export function fetchCommsmatricesByService(service_id) {
    const request = axios.get(`/api/user/comms/matrices/format/json?quiet=1&service_id=`+service_id);   
    return {
        type: FETCH_COMMSMATRICES_BY_SERVICE,
        payload: request
    };
}

export const APPROVE_COMMSMATRIX_SOX = 'approve_commsmatrix_sox';

export function approveCommsmatrixSox(id) {
    const params = 'approve=1';
    const request = axios.post(`/api/admin/rename/comms/matrices/id/`+id+`/format/json?quiet=1`,params);    
    return {
        type: APPROVE_COMMSMATRIX_SOX,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What I would do in this situation is to add an error variable to the state, and create another action for this error.

In your reducer

```
case ERROR:
return {
...state,
error: action.error
}
```

in your app's render function you check this error before your main return.

```
if(this.props.error) 
return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
            {this.props.error}
            </div>
        );
```

In your action, you simply check for error, and return an ERROR action when it exist. Maybe something like this.

```
let returnValue;
if(request.data.header.error !== null) {  
returnValue = {type: ERROR,payload: request.data.header.error}
} else {
returnValue = {
        type: FETCH_COMMSMATRIX,
        payload: request
    };
}
return returnValue;
```

Comment: how would it enter the `case ERROR:` in the reducer if i  will be running `case FETCH_COMMSMATRIX`? I have done what you mentioned. but no when i think about it i have to do this to every single action. is there a way to apply this globally?

Comment: let me see your actions.

Comment: I have added actions